# Snowflake External Table Replication from AWS Account to GCP account

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some external tables in my Snowflake primary account, which is on AWS region. I need to do data sharing in GCP snowflake accounts for same external tables. How can I replicate these external tables to GCP region or how can I create external table in GCP snowflake account and point those external tables files in AWS S3?

Comment: Duplicate of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69212056/snowflake-external-table-replication-from-aws-account-to-gcp-account. Recommend closing this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snowflake External Table Replication from AWS Account to GCP account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69212056/snowflake-external-table-replication-from-aws-account-to-gcp-account)

Answer (score 0):

you have to be really careful with Egress costs that the cloud provider charges. Moving data in is usually free but getting data out is not.

With that aside Snowflake does offer a replication service that you can configure under an ORG (similar to AWS ORGS); because essentially GCP and AWS run their own physical data centers, moving data between them could accumulate Egress charges.

Snowflake operates on top of a GCP or AWS. For a clear explanation refer to this doc on Snowflake replication: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/database-replication-intro.html